# Styling Ninja Forms button with CSS

Tags: css, forms, button, styles, ninja-forms

For this website:

https://pfiservices.net/

The button in the form appears in white characters on PC. The background is also white, so it can't be read. I'm trying to style it white.

I've tried this CSS:

```
#nf-field-11.ninja-forms-field.nf-element{
    color: #115172 !important;
    }
```

And this one:

```
.themebutton @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    color: #115172 !important;
    }
```

And many more.

Also, I've edited the Theme CSS which makes the text inherit that white color. It keeps loading the previous version.

Nothing seems to work. I don't know what to do anymore.

I appreciate any help on this issue.

Comment: For me, the button on the form is blue and when I hover over it it's white (and the background turns blue), so your first CSS block seems to work. I don't understand your question. Also, your CSS media query is incorrect. Check the [syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Comment: It seems like it's working as intended right now. I don't know why. Maybe some issue related to Wordpress cache.

Why do you indicate that the media query CSS is wrong? It need a subcategory like "body" as pointed in the example, it needs an extra space after (min-width: 768px), or both?